# inquire unformatted file fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran code that produces an unformatted file (.checkpoint). In the same code, I am trying to assign a value to a variable if the unformatted file exists, before the code creates it later. Here is part of the code:

```
    integer :: nt, irec1
    logical OK

    nt = 1
    a = 0
    inquire (file='.checkpoint', exist=OK)
    if (OK) then
    a = 1
    end if

    if(a .eq. 1) then
    inquire (iolength = irec1) nt
    open(unit=255, file='.checkpoint', status='unknown', form='unformatted', access='direct', recl=irec1)
    read(255,rec=1) nt
    go to 315
    end if

!do something here
315 nt = 2

    !Saving checkpoint file
    inquire (iolength = irec1) nt
    open(unit=255, file='.checkpoint', status='unknown', form='unformatted', access='direct', recl=irec1)
    write(255,rec=1) nt

    stop
    end
```

For the first run, **OK** should be false, and a = 0, since there is no .checkpoint file. If run the code using ifort compiler, I obtain a error message:

```
    forrtl: severe (36): attempt to access non-existent record, unit 255 ~/directory/.checkpoint
```

My question is how to first inquire if an unformatted file exists. If exists then assign a = 1. The above code works fine if the file is formatted. The main aim of this code is to restart calculation for molecular dynamics simulation.

Comment: Please show the complete code we can compile and run. See [mcve]. There should be no difference for formatted and unformatted in the code you show. Why does it have the [tag:gfortran] tag?

Comment: In addition to what @VladimirF has already written, it's always worth while using the `iomsg` and `iostat` specifiers when i/o statements go awry.

Comment: I do not get any error message with your test code. Did you try running this version? How exactly do you compile it? Which compiler version? Why the gfortran tag? You definitely should use `iostat=` or an equivalent.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the error message.  Can you please specify the compiler and compiler version that triggered the error?

Comment: ifort version is 2013_sp1.2.144. I am also loading FFTW module for compilation. I am using: module load ifort 2> /dev/null
module load FFTW  2> /dev/null
ifort code.f90 -lfftw3. Maybe this why I am getting the error.

Comment: As @VladimirF asked above, did you try running this version (exactly as you copied it here), and why the gfortran tag?  The sample code you posted does not require FFTW, and should not be affected by linking against -lfftw.  Note that we don't know what exactly those system modules are doing, and that redirecting the output of `module load` to `/dev/null` is a bad idea: if an error is happening there, you will not notice.

Comment: According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compiler-and-composer-update-version-numbers-to-compiler-version-number-mapping , you seem to be using the Linux version 14.0.2.144 20140120 of the Intel compiler.  I tried your code above with that compiler version, and everything was fine - no error produced.

Comment: I have removed the gfortran tag. FFTW module is required for the full code. Yes, I am getting the same error for the sample code shown above. Maybe I need to reinstall ifortran, since both of you do not have the error. Maybe it is corrupted in my system. Thanks to both ripero and VladimirF.

Comment: Based in my experience, it is more likely that you will gain some understanding on what is happening by using `iomsg` in the command, as advised above, than the possibility that your system is corrupted.

Comment: Please, Implicit None! Your use of a and hence real comparisons where a perfectly good logical exists is especially distressing...

Comment: @ripero The code is working fine now. I have reinstalled ifortran.

Comment: @IanBush Yes, there should be a Implicit none. It was declared in the main code. I forgot to add when make the minimal sample code.